# Data not received in PSA Table (SAP BW)

Tags: abap, netweaver, sap-bw

1. I installed SAP Netweaver Application Server 7.52 SP04 on my virtual box, it's working fine.
2. I have created Z* master data table and populated it with 2 mock records.
3. I created datasource via transaction RSO2.
4. I replicated data source via transaction RSDS.
5. I created necessary infoobject and its attributes in Data Warehousing Workbench and activated it.
6. I added newly created infoobject from step 5) as data tarrget.
7. I created transformation for the data target from step 6) and activated it.
8. I created infopackage for the replicated data source and clicked "Start" button in the "Schedule" tab of my infopackage (with option "Start immediately")
9. I check the monitor for infopackage where it says:
   "Data not received in PSA Table Diagnosis Data has not been updated in PSA Table . The request is probably still running or there was a short dump". (Please see screenshot below)[image]
10. I checked for short dumps - there are none.
11. Some googling gave recommendation to establish trusted connection in SM59, which I did (Please see screenshot below- I was logged as BWDEVELOPER)[image]
12. I ran "Start immediately" again in my infopackage and once again checked the monitor, now it says that I have no authorization to lig via trusted system. (Please see screenshot below)[image]
    The detailed warnings are like this: (Please see screenshot below)[image]

How do I fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't it related to missing IDOC partner profiles (WE20) for IDoc types RSRQST and RSINFO, in both directions? See https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=62260

Comment: I checked transaction WE20, RSRQST, RSINFO and RSSEND are in place. Any further ideas?

Comment: `Procedure: Make especially sure that the BW Add-ons for the source system have been correctly installed` did you check that? Is it demo trial or a licensed Netweaver? Where did you get it? Are you familiar with BASIS stuff and sure that your installation is correct?

Comment: It is demo trial Netweaver

Comment: @SandraRossi thank you, I found the problem. tRFCs were stuck in queue (SM58), after executing them manually everything works fine.

Comment: good to hear that

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with tRFCs which were stuck in queue (SM58). After manually executing LUWs data goes to PSA tables just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. To help future visitors, do you have any idea what was the reason? And now, is it okay whenever you run it again? Was the queue blocked or STOPped, and was it at BW side or at OLTP side?

Comment: queue was stopped on BW side, I couldn't establish the reason. The only idea is that it has to do with some default BASIS settings that preclude automatic processing of tRFCs.